# 'Consecutive Days Count' during server maintenance

Tags: discussion, consecutive-days, server, maintenance

So yesterday, when I visited SO, I saw it down for maintenance. The login was disabled & SO was running in a different mode of SO.

I couldn't help wondering, how SO keeps track of the consecutive days (and adds +1) at that particular moment, even though I was not logged in.

Maybe it's silly & I didnt look closely enough, but now that the time (of server maintenance) is over, I'd rather ask if anyone could share what they know.

Comment: It doesn't, because you're not logged in?

Comment: Apparently I use openID, & hence SO may or may not have had the login activity. What I meant to ask was, if there was something in the maintenance mode too, to collect all the login activity on SO & process it later when it comes back online...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not logins that count; it is *other* activities (browsing the site *while* logged in).

When the site is in read-only mode, such activity *cannot* be tracked (as that would require writing to the database).

The site was in read-only mode only for about an hour, if you accessed the site at any other time during the day (running from 00:00 UTC until 23:59:59 UTC) then your 'enthusiast' and 'fanatic' badges are safe still. :-)

Comment: So for the 1 hour, all the records are lost. Aah well, When so many things are done so right on a site, people raise their expectations ;)

Comment: No records are lost, no records were *made*. :-) When moving servers and a huge amount of data between data centers, some allowances must be made.. These things don't happen all that often, really.

Comment: How often do they happen? I've been visiting and browsing 8 different sites daily for just under a month (on some, others were only a couple weeks) trying really hard to make it to the fanatic badge and yesterday all my counts got reset because it didn't record my activity during maintenance (although strangely enough, one of the sites - A51 Meta - DID apparently record it...) Is there a posted schedule for it so I can avoid losing my credit in the future?

Comment: See https://www.stackstatus.net/ for Stack Exchange status news; this was a big move, I don't think there are any plans to do this again any time soon. It was not a regular thing.